# How do I add an overlay showing how many new items there are for my list?

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay

I have a refresh button in my title bar. It is the standard `ic_popup_sync` icon built into the framework for Android. I want to show some type of number next to or over top of the icon itself.

I thought about maybe just adding another menu item but I didn't want to waste space.

Here is my current item.

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"/>
```

**EDIT 1**

And I guess my problem is that I don't know the best way to handle adding an overlay or creating one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you use ActionBarSherlock, it would be quite simple

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//add your menu items
getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.YourMenuItems, menu);

final MenuItem refreshwithtext = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);    
//Implement your custom layout with imageview/button and textview on top
refreshwithtext.setActionView(R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
textontop = (TextView)refreshwithtext.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.your_text_id);

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

}

Comment: Wow I will take a look at this. Looks very very useful for supporting multiple platforms as well.